# Destructure.ByTransforming<System.Type> does not appear to take effect

Tags: .net, serilog

I am attempting to destructure `System.Type` by using just the type name, sans namespace, but am getting an unexpected result.

### Setup

The first transformation works as expected, producing the short string (the first 8 characters of a `Guid`). However, the second is never called:

```
.Destructure.ByTransforming<Id>(id => id.ToShortString())
.Destructure.ByTransforming<Type>(type => UseUnqualifiedName(type) ? type.Name : type.ToString())
```

### Usage

```
_logger.LogInfo("Instance loaded: {@Type}.{@Id}", typeof(MyProject.MyNamespace.MyType), id);
```

### Expected

> [INF] Instance: MyType.64b8ac0d

### Actual

> [INF] Instance: MyProject.MyNamespace.MyType.64b8ac0d

In addition, the fully-qualified name is green in the console output. I noticed this is also the case with `System.Uri`, and wonder if Serilog treats these types specially.

What can I do to affect the destructuring of `System.Type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems preventing the behavior you expect.

First, `Destructure.ByTransforming<T>()` is invariant for `T`, but at runtime you'll find that the "real" `System.Type` objects that you encounter are subclasses like `RuntimeType`.

A custom `IDestructuringPolicy` that applies to `System.Type` and its subclasses can work around this.

But, second, unfortunately - Serilog already has one of these that's plugged in by default:

https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Policies/ReflectionTypesScalarDestructuringPolicy.cs

Because `System.Type` can produce such enormous object graphs, and because of various footguns like the `RuntimeType` gotcha mentioned above, Serilog very early on disabled structured capturing of `System.Type` and various other reflection values.

To get around this, you need an `ILogEventEnricher` that detects property value matching `ScalarValue { Value: System.Type }` and replaces them with a modified `ScalarValue`.

```cs
// `Enrich.With(new RecaptureTypeEnricher())`
class RecaptureTypeEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        List<LogEventProperty> updates = null;
        foreach (var property in logEvent.Properties)
        {
            if (property.Value is ScalarValue { Value: Type type })
            {
                updates ??= new List<LogEventProperty>();
                updates.Add(new LogEventProperty(property.Key, new ScalarValue(UseUnqualifiedName(type))));
            }
        }

        if (updates != null)
        {
            foreach (var update in updates)
            {
                logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(update);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're just concerned about formatting, *Serilog.Expressions* might also offer up some options.

Comment: Thank you for the anwer! I tried the suggested approach, but unfortunately the corresponding `property.Value` comes through as a `string` instead of an instance of `Type`.

I could apply a convention where if the key ends in `Type`, attempt to parse the value as a fully-qualified type name and, if so, use the last segment. I may also dig into the Serilog code for a better understanding of the mechanics.

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Policies/ReflectionTypesScalarDestructuringPolicy.cs#L28 is where I'd expect the capturing to happen, but if you're seeing `string` instead of `Type`, is it possible you have an `@` missing in the message template?

Comment: That was it! I had `@` in the real code but forgot to use it in my test setup. Thanks again!